# Passing authorization data through headers of POST or GET request from Angular to a NodeJS server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, http-headers

On the one hand I have Angular running locally though port 9000 using gulp watch

And on the other I have a nodejs server running on port 3000.

Within Angular I am using the following code to POST/GET.

```
$scope.click = function(){
  console.log("clicked");

  var req = {
     method: 'POST',
     url: 'http://localhost:3000/hello?ids=1,2,3',
     // headers: {
       // 'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
       // ,'Authorization' : 'Basicbulletproof'
     // },
     data: {
      something: "some_data"
     }
    };
    success( function( data, status, headers, config ) {
      // something called here
      console.log( "SUCCESS! With data: ", data );
      console.log( "And status: ", status );
    }).
    error( function( data, status, headers, config ) {
      // something called here
      console.log( "ERROR! With data: ", data );
      console.log( "And status: ", status );   
    });
};
```

And on my node server I have:

```
app.all( '/*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type' );
  next();
});

app.post('/hello', function ( req, res ) {
  console.log( "HEADER: ", req.headers );
  console.log( "QUERY: ", req.query );
  console.log( "BODY: ", req.body );

  var metrics = {someData: "to send back to Angular"};
  res.send(metrics);

} );
```

When the click function is ran through Angular, on the NodeJS side I get the following:

```
OPTIONS /hello?ids=1,2,3 200 15.265 ms - 13
HEADER:  { host: 'localhost:3000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'content-length': '49',
  accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  origin: 'http://localhost:9000',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36',
  'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
  referer: 'http://localhost:9000/',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8' }
QUERY:  { ids: '1,2,3' }
BODY:  { something: 'some_data' }
POST /hello?ids=1,2,3 200 6.073 ms - 22
```

And on the Angular browser page I get:

```
clicked
SUCCESS! With data: Object {someData: "to send back to Angular"}
And status: 200
```

Which is all nice, but as soon as I try to alter the header by adding more elements to it from Angular it all goes Pete Tong...

Therefore what modifications do I need to include in order for me to pass authorization info like tokens from Angular to NodeJS on both sides to allow those to go through successfully?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: you should use get method....

Comment: @RavindraGalav thank you for this short answer but could you elaborate please, as I have also tried GET. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@Jules for angular

```
 $scope.click=function(){

  $http.post("http://localhost:3000/hello"+ids+"").success(function(data){    
//console.log(data);
    $scope.load=angular.fromJson(data);

  }).error(function(){alert("Error");
            });
}
```

and node server

```
app.all( '/*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type' );
  next();
});

app.post('/hello/:ids', function ( req, res ) {
  //console.log( "HEADER: ", req.headers );
  console.log( "QUERY: ", req.param.ids );
//  console.log( "BODY: ", req.body );

  var metrics = {someData: "to send back to Angular"};
  res.send(metrics);

} );
```

Comment: Thank you but how does your answer handle custom headers information to include tokens? Right your passing those through as queries making it visible on the URL

Comment: thank you for your response. I am still failing to see how your solution is passing custom header information? I am seeing queries being passed and body data which was already working in the version I laid out. But the issue is with regards to passing custom headers such as Authorization or something custom like 'X-custom-data' : 'whatever data' but in the header...

Answer (score 0):

First, your success() handler just returns the data, but that's not returned to the caller of getData() since it's already in a callback. $http is an asynchronous call that returns a $promise, so you have to register a callback for when the data is available.

I'd recommend looking up Promises and the $q library in AngularJS since they're the best way to pass around asynchronous calls between services.

For simplicity, here's your same code re-written with a function callback provided by the calling controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.service('dataService', function($http) {
delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
this.getData = function(callbackFunc) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://www.example.com/api/v1/page',
        params: 'limit=10, sort_by=created:desc',
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Token token=xxxxYYYYZzzz'}
     }).success(function(data){
        // With the data succesfully returned, call our callback
        callbackFunc(data);
    }).error(function(){
        alert("error");
    });
 }
});

myApp.controller('AngularJSCtrl', function($scope, dataService) {
    $scope.data = null;
    dataService.getData(function(dataResponse) {
        $scope.data = dataResponse;
    });
});
```

Now, $`http` actually already returns a $promise, so this can be re-written:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.service('dataService', function($http) {
delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
this.getData = function() {
    // $http() returns a $promise that we can add handlers with .then()
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://www.example.com/api/v1/page',
        params: 'limit=10, sort_by=created:desc',
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Token token=xxxxYYYYZzzz'}
     });
 }
});

myApp.controller('AngularJSCtrl', function($scope, dataService) {
    $scope.data = null;
    dataService.getData().then(function(dataResponse) {
        $scope.data = dataResponse;
    });
});
```

Finally, there's better ways to configure the $`http` service to handle the headers for you using `config`() to setup the $`httpProvider`. Checkout the $`http` documentation for examples.

Comment: Dear Ravindra, thank you for the suggestions, I managed to find a solution to my issues by adding Authorization to the setHeader as described in my solution. The information is now passed around successfully so all good there. Again many thanks for the helping hand and my apologies for the late response, I was traveling around.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.click = function(){
  console.log("clicked");

   var req = {
     method: 'POST',
     url: 'http://localhost:3000/hello?ids=1,2,3',
     headers: {
      'Authorization' : 'Basicbulletproof'
     },
     data: {
       something: "some_data"
     }
   };
   success( function( data, status, headers, config ) {
     // something called here
     console.log( "SUCCESS! With data: ", data );
     console.log( "And status: ", status );
   }).
   error( function( data, status, headers, config ) {
     // something called here
     console.log( "ERROR! With data: ", data );
     console.log( "And status: ", status );   
   });
 };
```

And on my node server I have:

```
 app.all( '/*', function(req, res, next) {
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type, Authorization' );
   next();
 });

 app.post('/hello', function ( req, res ) {
   console.log( "HEADER: ", req.headers );
   console.log( "QUERY: ", req.query );
   console.log( "BODY: ", req.body );

   var metrics = {someData: "to send back to Angular"};
   res.send(metrics);

 });
```

As you can see I was missing the "Authorization" on the node serve as part of the res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',...

And then on Angular side just setting the Header with the Authorization passes the information across to Nodejs successfully.